# knockout js bindng issue when using template binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

lets say i have a following code

```
var Names = ['test1','test2','test3'];
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.RegistraionInfo = ko.observableArray(Names);
    self.ChangeSelection = function (data,event) {
        fnChangeSelection(data);
    }
    self.tableRows = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addNewRow = function () {
        self.tableRows.push(new tableRow('', self));
    }

    self.addNewRow();
 }

 function tableRow(number, ownerViewModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.number = ko.observable(number);
    self.remove = function () {
        ownerViewModel.tableRows.destroy(this);
    }
 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and in html

```
                      <table >
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="template:{name:'data-tableRow', foreach: tableRows}"></tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <img id="btnAddRowProcedure1" src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/plus.png") data-bind="click: addNewRow" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>

<script id="data-tableRow" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <img id="btnDelete" src=@Url.Content("~/Content/img/close.png") data-bind="click: function(){ $data.remove(); }" />
        </td>
        <td><select data-bind="options:$root.RegistraionInfo, , event:{ change:$root.ChangeSelection}"></select></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

what im trying to do here is when user clicks the #btnAddRowProcedure1 link a new tablerow will be added. and inside the table row there is a dropdown that is bound to the Names array.when the user changes the dropdown selection the ChangeSelection function is called.
The Problem is that i want knock out to send currently selected Names array element as Data but knockout sending the tableRow as data.Is there a way to overcome this problem.Im still not sure why this works like this.

**UPDATE**

After the @Roy J changes i was able to get this to work.but now i have stumbled upon another problem (sorry im a noob at knockout).I want to add a button when ever the user changes the selection so i have added the following code to the ViewModel

```
    self.displayAddBtn = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.tableRows.length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return self.tableRows[self.tableRows.length-1].selected() !="";
    }, self);
```

this code is only executed once.when the user changes the selection this is code is not executed.can some one tell me how i can make this work

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `value` binding on your select. That's where the new value will show up when your change function is called.

```js
var Names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

function ViewModel() {

  var self = this;

  self.RegistraionInfo = ko.observableArray(Names);
  self.ChangeSelection = function(data, event) {
    console.debug("Changed to:", data.selected());
  }
  self.tableRows = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.addNewRow = function() {
    self.tableRows.push(new tableRow('', self));
  }

  self.addNewRow();
}

function tableRow(number, ownerViewModel) {
  var self = this;
  self.number = ko.observable(number);
  self.remove = function() {
    ownerViewModel.tableRows.destroy(this);
  };
  self.selected = ko.observable(); // new! bound to select
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="active">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template:{name:'data-tableRow', foreach: tableRows}"></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="btnAddRowProcedure1" src=@Url.Content( "~/Content/img/plus.png") data-bind="click: addNewRow" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<template id="data-tableRow">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img id="btnDelete" src=@Url.Content( "~/Content/img/close.png") data-bind="click: function(){ $data.remove(); }" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <select data-bind="options:$root.RegistraionInfo, value:selected, event:{ change:$root.ChangeSelection}"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to pass other data as well such as the id or the class of the element or the element it self

Comment: Anything you want in the view you should have bound to a variable in your model. The `css` binding can be used to bind classes, and the `attr` binding can bind an id. The event, from which you can get the element, is the 2nd argument to the click or change binding.